# How to properly manage an etag?

Tags: reactjs, etag

My SPA in ReactJS communicates to a backend coded in Python. They use `Eve`, and `Eve` sets an `etag` in its responses, so whenever trying to change some resource, an `etag` must be sent.

> An ETag is a hash value representing the current state of the resource on the server. Consumers are not allowed to edit (PATCH or PUT) or delete (DELETE) a resource unless they provide an up-to-date ETag for the resource they are attempting to edit. This prevents overwriting items with obsolete versions.

What's the best way to manage the `etag` when trying to edit a resource?